# ASP.Net 4: Custom error pages with correct HTTP status code, how?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

I'm running a ASP.Net 4 site on Windows 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.

When developing I use windows 7 and VS 2010 with IIS 7.5 as well.

I've setup my web.config as such:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error500.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

And my Error404.aspx page has this in its code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
}
```

On my developer machine this works fine, I see my pretty errorpage in the browser, and using Fiddler I can confirm I only receive the 404 HTTP status.

Now when I publish it to my server, it's a different story. Here I'll see the IIS' own 404 page ("C:\inetpub\custerr\en-US\404.htm")

If I remove the Response.StatusCode in my code-behind, I get the errorpage fine on the server, albeit with a 200 HTTP status.

What am I overlooking since this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [this article by Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/745738.aspx) help? It covers 500 errors and the TrySkipIisCustomErrors property to override the default IIS behaviour.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was reassigned to a different project temporarily. I'll check up on this tomorrow.